# React Refs return null or undefined when accessing reference to the DOM node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
App._this.check_input_value
src/App.js:36
  33 | 
  34 | check_input_value = () => {
  35 | 
> 36 |     if (this.ref1.current.value != undefined && this.ref1.current.value != null) {
  37 |         console.log(this.ref1.current.value);
  38 |     }
  39 | }
```

I also tried testing only one condition (both != null, and undefined, separately). Same error except I think when testing for != null only it said property was undefined instead.

The if statement was put in to solve the undefined/null value errors and removing it just produces the same errors on the next statement.

I start with a default value in the input being referenced, so that should not be an issue:

```
// inside render()
<form action="">
      <input
         type="text"
         ref={this.ref1}
         value='10'
         onChange={(e) => this.update_input_field(e)} />
      <button
          onClick={this.check_input_value()} >
          Check input value
      </button>

// Towards the top of the component, outside the constructor:
ref1 = React.createRef();
```

I also tried setting `this.ref1 = React.createRef()` inside the constructor. Same error.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.ref1 = React.createRef();
}
```

Does anyone know why the this.ref1.current returns undefined or null?

Any solutions to the above are also welcome, thanks.

Comment: which version of react do you use

Comment: Calling React.version returns: 16.4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only can access the ref after componentDidMount. I found a mistake here:

```
<button
  onClick={this.check_input_value()} >
  Check input value
</button>
```

the `this.check_input_value` will invoke when render instead of onClick, before `componentDidMount` and ref1 is null. just change to this

```
<button
  onClick={this.check_input_value} >
  Check input value
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason `ref1` is not set is because you invoke `check_input_value` straight away on render:

```
<button onClick={this.check_input_value()}>Check input value</button>
```

You should instead give `onClick` function reference, so the function can be called when the event occurs. This way the `ref1` will be set, since it is set after the first render, and the event handler will be called when you expect.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  ref1 = React.createRef();

  check_input_value = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.ref1.current.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.check_input_value}>
        <input type="text" ref={this.ref1} />
        <button>Check input value</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.4.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.4.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got spesific problem I tried to hide and show with return null element.But I got problem when I send null to child then I try to access ref from useEffect I got undefined error because If you return null component lifecycle still continue. So I receive undefined error when unmount moment so I search useLayoutEffect and useEffect differences on react docs and put debugger useEffect and useLayoutEffect. I notice useLAyoutEffect works before painted dom but dom still hold by react. So I put useLayoutEffect inside return arrow function now I can access my ref without error.

[More Details](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/08/10/react-v17-rc.html#effect-cleanup-timing)

```js
  // dont use useEffect when you access null component from parent
  useEffect(() => {
        const onMouseLeave = (event) => {
           event.stopPropagation();
           console.log('mouse leaved')
        }
           ref!.current.addEventListener("mouseleave", onMouseLeave);

        // componentWillUnmount add cleanup functions
        return () => {
          //here error
          // ref.current return null
         ref!.current.removeEventListener("mouseleave", onMouseLeave);

        }
    }, []);

    // here working version we can access null component from parent because useLayoutEffect works before dom painted and before dom update
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const onMouseEnter = (event) => {
            event.stopPropagation();
            ref.current!.focus();
        }


         ref.current.addEventListener("mouseenter", onMouseEnter);

        // componentWillUnmount add cleanup functions
        return () => {
            ref.current!.removeEventListener("mouseenter", onMouseEnter);

        }
    }, []);
```